Unable to use pathlib.Path with OSGeo OGR CreateDataSource()
I have a function that takes an arbitrary WKB geometry (e.g. ogr.wkbPolygon) and a pathlib.Path called geojson_path and writes it as a GeoJSON file.
For that I have the following lines (init of GeoJSON driver and creating the data source where the feature(s) will be written to).
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('GeoJSON')
data_src = driver.CreateDataSource(geojson_path)
...

If I use a pure string e.g. tmp/test.geojson for geojson_path I get an instance. However, if I use my pathlib.Path with the same value, I get None. Explicitly converting the path to an absolute one and/or to a string (using __str__()) does not yield a different result.

Interestingly enough once I added unlink() (better use missing_ok to avoid raising exception if the file is not present) in order to remove the file that is used as an output data source, it works.

Best call gdal.UseExceptions() after importing gdal so you get a proper (and hopeflully clear) exception when something goes wrong as explained here.
